# Pandas variable path

Tags: python, excel, pandas, user-interface, tkinter

I'm writing  in python a simple excel into folder software using tkinter and pandas.
The first step of this program will be the file choice so I wrote:

```
data_path=StringVar()

def getPath():
    file = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r', initialdir='/',
            filetypes=[("xlsx files", "*.xlsx")])
if file:
    filepath=os.path.abspath(file.name)
    data_path.set(filepath)
    Label(root, textvariable=data_path).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='w', padx=100)
    
labels1_1 = Label (root, text = "Carica un File", 
                    font=('Arial', 12, 'bold')).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,sticky='w')

open_button = Button (root, text="Scegli un File", 
                    command=getPath).grid(row=1,column=0, padx=13, pady=5,sticky='w')
```

But if I set "data_path" as string and than I put into:

```
df = pd.read_excel(data_path)
```

It doesn't work.
So how can I read the dataframe from user's excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data_path` is an instance of `StringVar`, what you need is to get the value of it, so you have to use `get()` method to get its value:

```
df = pd.read_excel(data_path.get())
```

Furthermore, you don't need `askopenfile`, you can just use `askopenfilename` which will return the absolute path of the file.

```
def getPath():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/',
            filetypes=[("xlsx files", "*.xlsx")])
    if file:
        data_path.set(file)
        Label(root, textvariable=data_path).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='w', padx=100)
```